# How close to asking about chemistry can I get while remaining on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to ask a question like this:

> Raffinose is a sugar found in legumes that is indigestible by humans.  Which is great, because I'm looking for a sweetener that 1) won't raise blood sugar and 2) doesn't have a bitter aftertaste and isn't carcinogenic or whatever else.  The question I have is whether raffinose breaks down during cooking?  If heat can decompose it into other sugars then it's useless for my purposes.

While I'm asking about cooking and for the purposes of cooking, this can also be viewed as a chemistry question about the stability of a chemical.  Is it on-topic?  And whether yes or no, where is the line in general for questions like this?

Comment: I find it very cool that people ask such questions, and would have given you multiple upvotes if I could.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Might be a little esoteric as far as getting a reliable answer is concerned, but certainly, questions about the science of cooking are on topic, and questions about the effects of cooking on nutritional properties, such as [this one about Vitamin C](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/17379/41), are no problem at all.

Comment: Great, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

My 2 cents:

With molecular gastronomy becoming a trendy cooking style, I feel like deep, esoteric questions related to food properties and preparation are perfectly valid--pushing the boundaries of accessible cooking.  I personally welcome questions such as these.